# CakePHP Router with slug and language

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, url-routing

I am a bit in dead end trying to mane my routes in CakePHP. I read almost every article in the www and some of them close to what i need but combining with other dont work as expected. Also tried some router lib-s, but the same

Here is what I need:

Both language parameter in the url and a slug of the pages. So:

> ***for the frontend***
>
> the directory '/' should lead to the default language, `controller` => `pages` , `slug` => `home`
>
> /:lang - the same as above but with selected language
>
> /:slug - `controller` => `pages` , `action` => `index` and to pass the `:slug` parameter, with default language
>
> /:lang/:slug - the same as above with set lang parameter
>
> /:controller/:slug -
>
> /:lang/:controller/:slug - the same as above with set lang parameter
>
> - I dont need any `action`-s in those links
>
> ***for the admin panel***
>
> /admin - 'controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'index'
>
> /admin/:controller/:action/ .... this one is the default
>
> - no need for language parameter in the admin url, but actions exists, **except the index action**

Also how should I create the links inside the view, so the routers to be working as the should?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Router::connect("/admin", array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'settings', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
    Router::connect("/admin/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
    Router::connect("/admin/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));

    Router::connect("/:language/*", array('action' => 'home', 'controller' => 'pages'));
    Router::connect("/:language/:controller", array('action' => 'index'));
    Router::connect("/:language/:controller/*");
```

You can copy past the second set of routes, but changing :language to slug, you should put it in an if and validate the language given, if it doesn't validate then load the slug routes.

Comment: Thanks, with little editing works perfect. But how to create a change-languages-link
This does not work:


`$this->Html->link(__('Lala', true), array_merge($this->passedArgs, array('language' => 'eng')));`

Comment: What does it output? It should work. I'm not sure the $this->passedArgs gives you the data you need, print that array out and see if you're passing a controller and action.

Comment: the `$this->passedArgs` is passing only the slug, what else can I use?

Comment: Controller and action, check the documentation for info.